# Properly assigning delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object for iOS Mobile Blazor Bindings

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I was following [this tutorial](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#setting-up-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-client-app-on-ios) to implement notifications through FCM. At their [Register for remote notifications](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#register-for-remote-notifications) section there is a code snippet:

Project.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:

```
// Register your app for remote notifications.
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (10, 0)) {
    
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

    var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization (authOptions, (granted, error) => {
        Console.WriteLine (granted);
    });
} else {
    // iOS 9 or before
    var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
    var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (allNotificationTypes, null);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (settings);
}

UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
```

So seems like there are no problem but when I implemented this to my MBB hybrid project the line:
`UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;`
gives an error, saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApp.iOS.AppDelegate' to UserNotifications.IUNUserNotificationsCenterDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists`

It won't let me compile but if I explicitly cast it into what it wants it also gives error.

Found [another example](https://gist.github.com/codercampos/7084dd0e9d0f47b0a306122f9da248e9#file-firebaseappdelegate-cs) of Xamarin Forms [at this post](https://xamarinlatino.com/xamarin-forms-firebase-cloud-messaging-ios-setup-1961a91d4055) (I translated mostly since I don't know Spanish) and they're doing the same.

What's the correct way to cast register for notifications for Mobile Blazor Bindings project -if this is because I'm using MBB rather than Xamarin Forms?

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create Hybrid Mobile Blazor Bindings Project (preview 5)
2. At Project.iOS/AppDelegate.cs, adding `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;` gives error of `Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project.iOS.AppDelegate' to 'UserNotifications.IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`
3. If explicit cast is applied, it gives error too saying it can't convert.

#### Expected Behavior

- Receive Notifications successfully.

#### Actual Behavior

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found that I didn't include the necessary Interfaces. `AppDelegate` class should look like this.

```
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful for me, but I am still not able to receive notifications. Do you have a solution posted on GitHub or something that could help me?

Comment: Its crazy how bad the documentation is for new comers. Been trying to figure this out forever